Emacs keys (C-d) stop working
Running GNU Emacs 29.4 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.42, cairo version 1.18.0) of 2024-07-16, with the bepo keyboard and the ergoemacs (but I highly doubt it is the issue) package, the keybinding C-c C-d stopped working.
To be clear, the key binding is bound to org-deadline properly, but the issue is not an error from org, it is just that Emacs does not see the C-d input. I can see it is not being recorded because in the minibuffer it shows me the sequence of the keybinding. It takes into account C-c but not C-d.
Couple of days ago it was working. I have not updated Emacs since then, nor any package from my init.el file. Changing my keyboard input method from bepo to classic qwerty, the issue remains.
I have really no idea what’s going on, and don’t know how to debug it. Help please!

Does C-d work in other applications or systems?

Does C-d works from emacs -Q? I would start from here.

"the key binding is bound to org-deadline properly" This means C-h k C-d shows you org-deadline?

@Tekki: that should read C-h k C-c C-d shows you org-deadline? but it is indeed a good question: if the OP cannot type C-d, how does the OP determine that the key is bound to org-deadline properly? To be clear, there are ways to do that (e.g. examine the appropriate keymap), but a clarification from the OP does seem indicated.

One additional debugging step (assuming you are running on X11) is to invoke xev from a command line and type C-d into the little window: does it show ^D events?

@TianshuWang C-d works. I checked using Gnome view keyboard layout option from the settings pane.

@Tekki I cannot type C-h k C-d, but using C-h b that lists all key bindings, last time I checked it was bound to org-deadline. But again, the issue is not really the binding, rather it is that I cannot input the C-d command anywhere.

@NickD I am running on Wayland

@ManuelUberti C-d does not work either from emacs -Q. It is the same problem, it does not input the keybinding at all.

Try another keyboard?

"I'm running on Wayland..." - so am I (I'm on Fedora 40), but I'm also running Xwayland and xev works fine. Maybe you can try that... But reading back some more, maybe the Gnome view keyboard layout answers that question.

@NickD I’m on Fedora 40 as well. I don’t have another keyboard at hand, but other keyboard layouts have the same issue. Also, xev did work. The output is cryptic to me. What I see is that when I type C-c or just C it logs events, but typing C-d does not log anything.
